# Where/how should I create a viewmodel via LINQ projection from a domain entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-core, repository

To create a viewmodel I typically

1. Use a repository to fetch the required entities, and
2. Map to a viewmodel (which can be done in various ways, e.g. in the controller, using AutoMapper, in a service class, etc.)

But what if I have "wide" tables, so I need to create viewmodels using LINQ projections? So I want the `Id` and `Name` properties from the `Product` entity, and the `Id` property from `Customer` entity - but I don't want the rest, because that's expensive.

So I need access to the `IQueryable<>`, which is available only in the context and repositories.

My options:

- Create the viewmodel inside the repository. But that means domain and UI are tightly coupled. It also means the UI classes must be in the same assembly as the domain.
- Expose `IQueryable<>` from the repository, and allow a service class (or controller) to perform the projection, and map to the viewmodel. But that "leaks" the domain into the services and UI.
- ?

So when loading the entire entity, it's easy to keep everything neat. But when loading via projection, it's tricky.

Do I have any other/better options?

---

**EDIT:** No this is not a duplicate question. Seriously, that one starts with the text *"I have a problem in understanding the purpose of a ViewModel."*

Comment: You can always create light Db views from your "wide" tables. And query "light" POCOs that could be mapped to your viewmodels

Comment: @AlexArt. That's certainly an option, but it seems like I'd just be pushing the problem into the database, instead of just dealing with it.